# How to break word in text area in razor form?

Tags: c#

How to break the word in text-area in razor form?

I am using text-area in my form. It looks bad  when I write a long text on my table. I want something like, after some text my text come in .....(doted form) ..then in tool-tip I want to see the whole note.

This is my text-area

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note)
     @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Note, new { @placeholder = "Enter Note", @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%; max-width: 100%;", @rows = "4"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
 </div>
```

and my table

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactPerson2)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)</td>
```

Comment: CSS [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) for "...", HTML `title` for tooltip.

Comment: You could make that comment into an answer because it's probably the best solution to this scenario.

Comment: @Amadan, how to use tooltip in html

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi: Naa, I'll just throw a +1 on cbp :P

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean that you want the text in your *table* (or rather, your *td*) to be cut off with an ellipsis ("…") if it is too long. Your textarea should already have scrollbars if the text is too long.

There's actually a few things you need to do.

You can use CSS's `text-overflow: ellipsis`. But you probably also need to apply a `width`, `height`, `overflow: hidden`, and `white-space: nowrap`. You may also need to wrap your text in a `div`.

You can then use the `title` attribute to show the full text as a tooltip.

Here is a rough example:

```
<td title="@Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.Note)"><div style="text-overflow: ellipsis; width:100px; height:20px; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Note)</div></td>
```

Note there are a lot of ways the above could be better, this just gives you a starting point.

Comment: Yes, I want exactly the same I have added all this as you said but I am not getting your last line to wrap in a div, can you please explain it with my code

Comment: I've added an example. Apologies if my Razor isn't quite right... I haven't coded Razor in a while.

Comment: Thank u so much, it is working now...but instead of title I want to show the tooltip